# Using Advanced Custom Field value as "Email to" in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

I'm creating a page in which you submit a Contact Form 7 to the email based on what email is added to the job_email field via my Advanced Custom Fields.

[image]

I have attempted to add the form via the PHP shortcode like this

`[email* dynamic-email class:email-address placeholder "Email Address*"]`

`echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="234" title="Dynamic Submit CV" dynamic-email="'.get_field( 'job_email' ).'"]' );`

The fields all display correctly, and upon submitting the email successfully, the email never receives the form. Meaning I am totally missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are after is send a notification with the entry details to the email address inputted on the `job_email` field.

If so, what you want to do is to [set up an email on the email tab](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/) and in the `To:` setting put `[job_email]`.

#### Update

As you stated in the comment, the email has to be the one set in the backend. You can guarantee the email notification to be sent to the ACF-based email via hooks, specifically the [`wpcf7_mail_components`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/trunk/includes/classes.php?rev=160875#L347) hook.

```
function so57013385_mail_components( $components, $number ) {
    $job_mail = get_field( ... );

    $components['recipient']   = (array) $components['recipient'];
    $components['recipient'][] = $job_mail;

    return $components;
};
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'so57013385_mail_components', 10, 2 );
```

*Note: I'm casting the `$components['recipient']` variable to array just to make sure the email is appended correctly, as this parameter is passed directly to [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), which can receive a `string` or an `array`. Also, you might need to add more validations on the form ID, sanitization, etc. The above code is not tested.*

Comment: Not entirely sure.The client will be able to put any email in the `job_email` ACF field for each job, this email differs from job to job. Meaning when that contact form is filled out, it needs to go to the email that is assigned to that job.

Comment: @CharlieMcShane I just updated the answer, please take a look and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Using ACF value as Email in CTF7 after submit received on Email.

**solution:** https://moometric.com/integrations/wp/contact-form-7-dynamic-attachments-using-custom-upload-field/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34298099)